# Vue component's (select) on-change function not called if value set from external method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am using a Select as a Vue component and define it as a template.I am having the components data and props defined.

```js
var MyComponent = Vue.component('my-component',{

  template: "<select v-on:change=\"onAppSelected\" \n"+ 
  "v-model:value=\"appId\">           \n"+
  "<option v-for=\"appChoice in appChoices\"   \n"+
  "v-bind:value=\"appChoice.id\">{{appChoice.name}} \n"+
  "</option>          \n"+
  "</select>",
 
  methods: {
   onAppSelected:function(event){
     console.log("On Change Called:", this.item.serial)
     console.log("Event Target:",event.target.value)      
    },
   setValue: function(selValue) {
     this.appId = selValue;      
    },
  }, 
});
```

The function **onAppSelected** defined in the template using v-on:change is called if the option is selected from drop down manually.

But that function **onAppSelected** dont get triggered if the Value of the Select is set from the method **setValue**.

The **setValue** method is called from a external button.

The jquery lib .trigger("change") also dont help in this case.

[jsFiddle Full Code](https://jsfiddle.net/Thevananthan/Lx0y5tpo/)

The link for the full implementation in the js fiddle is added for testing.
check the output in console.

Can any one help me on this.
Thanks in advance for reading my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [change | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change),

change fires for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements when an alteration to the element's value is committed by the user. Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily fired for each alteration to an element's value.

This means that the change event will only be triggered if the value is "changed" by user. Also it won't fire if the user selects the same value.

You may use "watch" for detecting changes: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ctLweh5/)

Comment: Thank you @Tang for the help, the Vue watch is helping much to solve this requirement.